# Remove tags within Smarty tag

Tags: php, html, smarty

I'm wondering if you know of a way on removing tags from a smarty tag ?.

The tag that i'm using is {$menu} that is outputting the following:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

but what i'm trying to do is removing the

```
<ul></ul>
```

Do you know of an easy way doing this within the smarty tag?.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, found the solution.

```
{menu|replace:'<ul>':''|replace:'</ul>':''}
```

This works, if you have any other way, please share.